# Adding the AngularJS Currency Locale to the end

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I have the following markup:

```
<div class="full">
    <dl class="no-margin">
        <dt ng-if="foo.IsLoading" class="no-margin text--plain">
        <img alt="Load animation" src="load_small.gif"/> Loading
        </dt>
        <dt ng-if="!foo.IsLoading" class="no-margin text--plain">{{foo.BalanceLabel}}</dt>
        <dd class="h3 text--plain" ng-class="{' text--negative': model.IsNegativeBalance(foo.BalanceValue)}">{{foo.BalanceValue | currency:"CAD"}}</dd>
    </dl>
</div>
```

The only problem is that it adds the 3 digit value to the beginning of the value: "CAD1,234.56" or "-CAD1,234.56"

This is fine for USD as we want the $ in the front. However, my design requires the foreign 3 digits to be at the end of the amount: "1,234.56 CAD" or "-1,234.56 CAD"

Can I still use the Angular currency API to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't solve it with currency filter.
You're two options to solve your issue.

**Fix 1 :**

Use i18n angular (de for example)

```
<script src="i18n/angular-locale_de-de.js"></script>
```

**Fix 2 :**

Use filter number with currency without currency filter

```
{{foo.BalanceValue | number:2}}CAD
```

For Fix 1 I'm not sure to work with the currency CAD. I only try with €.